How can I fill a variable length HTML table from JavaScript
I need to fill in an HTML table from JS (I have just started with JS).  Here is my code based on an example I found:


length = Table.length
const Table = document.getElementById("TblBody")
for ( i = 0; i<length; i++ )
{ let row = Table.insertRow();
  let cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
  cell0.innerHTML = NameTable[i][0];
  cell1.innerHTML = NameTable[i][1];
  cell3.innerHTML = NameTable[i][2];
  cell4.innerHTML = NameTable[i][3];
}
<table id="myTable" border="1" style="display:none; width:500px; float: left">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>....</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Nick Name</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TblBody"></tbody>
</table>



I expected to see about 20 rows of five columns each filled with data.
The results I got with the above code:
the headers displayed as expected
boxes for the first two columns were displayed
neither box had any data

The code shown appears to be producing an error.  Is this also happening in your browser?  If not, can you update the code snippet in the question to demonstrate the problem?

What NameTable is supposed to be ?

do Simply :


const myTblBody = document.querySelector('#myTable > tbody');

for ( let [ Name, Address, Phone, NickName ] of NameTable )
  {
  let row = myTblBody.insertRow();
  row.insertCell().textContent = Name;
  row.insertCell().textContent = Address;
  row.insertCell(); 
  row.insertCell().textContent = Phone;
  row.insertCell().textContent = NickName;
  }
table {
  background      : darkblue;
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing  : 1px;
  margin-bottom   : .8em;
  }
table caption {
  font-size   : 1.4rem;
  font-weight : bold;
  padding     : .4em 0;
  }
th {
  background-color : #7fccff;
  padding          : .4em .6em ;
  }
td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .2em .7em;
  text-align       : center;
  }
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>....</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Nick Name</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script>
const NameTable =
  [ [ 'John Doe', '123 Main St', '555-1234', 'Johnny'] 
  , [ 'Jane Smith', '456 Elm St', '555-5678', 'Janey'] 
  , [ 'Alice Johnson', '789 Oak St', '555-9876', 'Ali']
  , [ 'Larry Cicchinelli', '727 5th Avenue', '755-8000', 'Tiff'] 
  ];
</script>




You are trying to use the Table variable before it is defined. You should declare the const Table before using it.


const people = [
  ["John Doe", "123 Main St", '', "555-1234", "Johnny"],
  ["Jane Smith", "456 Elm St", '', "555-5678", "Janey"],
  ["Alice Johnson", "789 Oak St", '', "555-9876", "Ali"],
];

const tableBody = document.getElementById("TblBody");

const length = people.length;

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let row = tableBody.insertRow();

    let cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
    let cell4 = row.insertCell(4);

    cell0.innerHTML = people[i][0];
    cell1.innerHTML = people[i][1];
    cell2.innerHTML = people[i][2];
    cell3.innerHTML = people[i][3];
    cell4.innerHTML = people[i][4];
}
<table>
  <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>....</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Nick Name</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TblBody"></tbody>
</table>



document.getElementById("myTable").style.display = "block";
I haven't tested this code; it would be best if you could show the array with some example data.

When manipulating the DOM you should aim to change it as little as possible, as each change will require the browser to render the whole page.
The following snippet uses a template-string based approach and creates the whole HTML of the table body in one go and then imports it into the table by using element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',...).
This method allows the injection of HTML code into existing elements without destroying potentially existing event listener definitions relating to that element.
Maybe it is a little bit silly but, as you can see below, the whole thing can then be done as a "one-liner", without the need of defining variables on the way:


const people = [
  ["John Doe", "123 Main St", '', "555-1234", "Johnny"],
  ["Jane Smith", "456 Elm St", '', "555-5678", "Janey"],
  ["Alice Johnson", "789 Oak St", '', "555-9876", "Ali"],
];

document.getElementById("TblBody").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",people.map(p=>"<tr>"+p.map(a=>`<td>${a}</td>`).join("")+"<tr>").join("\n"));
<table>
  <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>....</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Nick Name</th>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="TblBody"></tbody>
</table>



